# How to fix TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

I'm having a python error but I don't know how to fix it. Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/Documents/venvs/socket_search.py", line 21, in <module>
   main()
   File "/home/Documents/venvs/socket_search.py", line 19, in main
   print("[+]" + ip + "/" + str(port) + " : " + banner.strip('/n'))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Here is my code:

```
import socket

def retBanner(ip,port):
        try:
                socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
                s = socket.socket()
                s.connect((ip,port))
                banner = s.recv(1024)
                return banner
        except:
                return


def main():
        ip = input("[*] Enter Target IP: ")
        for port in range(1,100):
                banner = retBanner(ip,port)
                if banner:
                        print("[+]" + ip + "/" + str(port) + " : " + banner.strip('/n'))

main()
```

Please give me solution for this error

Comment: Please, add full traceback to your question. It'll help quite a bit.

Comment: Need the full error and line pls

Comment: But probably your `banner`variable is bytes, not str. So use `str(banner)`in your print call.

Comment: @ex4 that would cause the reverse error.

Comment: @Sören you are right. Should transform str to bytes, not other way around. Should think before writing.

Comment: @ex4 But socket.recv() does return a bytes object. That's why OP should post the full traceback, instead of us having to resort to guesswork.

Comment: @soren I though that, but the return is a bytes and using strip() on it causes the error.  Just need to str it first and all good. I tested with print(type(banner)).

Comment: yeah, problem is calling strip on a bytes with a str arg, e.g. `b"100".strip("0")`, where `banner` is the bytes object in OP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html) object and you are using the [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) method which required a str.  If you simply convert that first, you're golden, just a small change:

```
import socket

def retBanner(ip,port):
        try:
                socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
                s = socket.socket()
                s.connect((ip,port))
                banner = s.recv(1024)
                return banner
        except:
                return


def main():
        ip = input("[*] Enter Target IP: ")
        for port in range(1,100):
                banner = retBanner(ip, port)
                if banner:
                    print("[+]" + ip + "/" + str(port) + " : " + str(banner).strip('/n'))

main()
```